# jQuery Datatable Sorted Row

Tags: jquery, datatable

**Note: I will be hiding the data column and hence I have to use jQuery Datatable API.**

For my jQuery Datatable, each row have a button beside it. 
The purpose of the button is to retrieve the column data.
The column data will be hidden.

For my button click event, this is my code.

```
    $('#Table').on('click', '.Button', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var rowindex = tr.index();
        //Get row based on index
        var rowData = $("#Table").DataTable().row(rowindex).data();
        var data = rowData.Data;
    });
```

This code is working, however there is one problem.
It is not able to retrieve the data of the sorted column.

For example, before Sorting,
Row 1 - Index 0  Data - A
Row 2 - Index 1  Data - B

After sorting,
Row 2 - Index 0  Data - B
Row 1 - Index 1  Data - A


Clicked on Data B row button, 
Data Gotten: A

Hopefully I have explained my problem clear enough. Thanks!

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mt4zrm4b/3/

Comment: You are very clear in your explanation, but it will be a great help if u can create fiddle for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass in your selector `tr` as the `rowSelector` parameter for [`row()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row()).

> DOM elements can be given as a row selector to select a row in the DataTabels API from that DOM element. This can be useful for getting data from a row, or performing other row based operations, when you have only the DOM node for reference, for example in an event handler.

The reason is because if you were to sort, the row indexes that DataTables doesn't get updated. It's recommended to select the row via your `tr`, like this:

```
$('#Table').on('click', '.Button', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");

    // Get row based on tr instead.
    var rowData = $("#Table").DataTable().row(tr).data();
    var data = rowData.Data;
    alert(data);
});
```

See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt4zrm4b/7/) for an example.

Comment: That's the answer I'm looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the value of the second `td` you can use

```
alert(tr.find("td:nth-child(2)").text());
```

In your code you have the entire row of interest and you can search in it as a DOM element.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not stating it clear enough. I will be hiding the data column and hence I have to use Jquery Datatable api.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var object = {
        "Data": "A",
        "Id": "1"
      };
      var objectB = {
        "Data": "B",
        "Id": "2"
      };
      var dataSet = [];
      dataSet.push(object);
      dataSet.push(objectB);

      console.log(dataSet);

      var table = $('#Table').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
        columns: [{
          'data': null,
        }, {
          'data': 'Id',
        }, {
          'data': 'Data',
        }, {
          'data': null,
        }],
        "oLanguage": {
          "sEmptyTable": "Error: Empty Table. Please create a new question"
        },
        "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
          $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex + 1);
          return nRow;
        },
        'columnDefs': [{
          'targets': [0],
          'searchable': true,
          'orderable': false
        }, {
          "targets": [1],
          "visible": false,
          "searchable": false
        }, {
          'targets': [-1],
          'searchable': false,
          'orderable': false,
          'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning Button">Get ID</button>';
          }
        }],
        bProcessing: true,
        bStateSave: false,
        bPaginate: true,
      })

      var rowCount = $('#QuizTb').on('order.dt search.dt', function() {
        table.column(0, {
          search: 'applied'
        }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
          cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
        });
      });

      $('#Table').on('click', '.Button', function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");            
        var data = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text();
        alert(data);
      });
```